# How do I create a database for my flutter mobile app?

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, mobile-application

**THE MATTER IS AS FOLLOWS**

The application consists in **calculating the salary** depending on how many extra hours and normal hours you worked in the respective month and I reached the point where **I have to create a database** that contains the name, email, start time and end time (from what time, until what time he worked on that day), and the date he entered this schedule

What does the user do when he enters the application, he must click on a date from the calendar where he has **START TIME AND END TIME**, after entering this, he can save, this should be done on the days when he works obviously, and in in this schedule, 8 hours should be recognized as normal hours, and if it exceeds 8 hours, then the rest of the hours should be additional hours,and at the end of the month to calculate the salary

---

*Edit:*

I searched and finally found Firebase, with this  I helped myself in the authentication part where it was ok, but in the database part I don't understand what the steps are and what I have to do exactly, I'm struggling with Firebase in this chapter, and I would like to know if I chose Firebase correctly and if so, then what I have to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) and [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) you will find the documentation on their respective pages.

**Save data**

To save data for an employee in one day, you can proceed like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('work_time').add({
  'email': 'johndoe@example.com',
  'startTime': startDateTime,
  'endTime': endDateTime,
});
```

**Get data**

Here is how you can get all the work time info of a specific employee in a month

```
final String email = 'johndoe@example.com';
final int month = 12; // December
final startDate = DateTime(2023, month, 1);
final endDate = DateTime(2023, month + 1, 0); // First day of next month

final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('work_time')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
    .where('startTime', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
    .where('endTime', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)
    .get();
```

**Calculate salary**

For each occurence calculate the hours worked, extra hours and addition the salary.

```
double hourlyRate = 20.0; // Replace with your actual rate
double overtimeRate = hourlyRate * 1.5; // Example overtime rate calculation
double totalSalary = 0;
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {

  DateTime startDateTime = doc.data()['startTime'];
  DateTime endDateTime = doc.data()['endTime'];
  Duration totalDuration = endDateTime.difference(startDateTime);
  double totalHours = totalDuration.inHours;
  double extraHours = 0.0;
  
  if (totalHours > 8) {
    extraHours = totalHours - 8;
    totalHours = 8;
  }

  // Calculate regular salary and overtime pay
  double regularSalary = totalHours * hourlyRate;
  double overtimePay = extraHours * overtimeRate;

  // Calculate total salary
  totalSalary += regularSalary + overtimePay;
}
print("Salary: $totalSalary");
```